# Django: Messages Framework

Tags: django, admin

So I have installed the new Messages Framework. The documentation mentions using a css class called "messages" in the template. But I can't seem to find any such css class in any of the files in the trunk. 
What I want to do is, in the Django Admin, have a red cross, instead of a green v, when displaying an error.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#ref-contrib-messages

Comment: I say forget about the CSS file. View the outputted HTML source code, and make your own CSS based on that.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, I will go ahead and do that.

Comment: Actually, how do I differentiate between the Message Tags in the CSS class? I need some dynamic solution here right?

Comment: Never mind, it does actually differentiate by the css classes error and info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the styling for .messages in your own CSS file, there doesn't need to be one already defined in the trunk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if we all have to define our own classes for the Django Admin, why not supply it by default?

Comment: Because logically what you need is change styles. All style changes should be done in css. NOTE: you do not need to change any files from django trunk - just extends admin/base_site.html template with your styles